# Scalaz validation

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

I'm trying to use scalaz validation in our project and have ran into a following situation:

```
def rate(username: String, params: Map[String, String]): ValidationNEL[String, Int] = {
  val voteV:Validation[String, RateVote] = validate(params, "vote") flatMap {v: String => RateVote(v)}
  val voterV:Validation[String, Sring] = validate(params, "voter")

  ... 
}
```

Now I have to return ValidationNEL containing possible parameter errors, if there were any, or use validated parameters to call the method:

```
storage.rate(username, voter, vote): Validation[String, Int]
```

I know, I could use |@| for the first part, but this code

```
(voterV.liftFailNel |@| voteV.liftFailNel) { (voter, rv) =>
  storage.rate(username, voter, rv)
}
```

will return `ValidationNEL[String, Validation[String, Int]]`. Is there a way to "flatten" this result, to get the `ValidationNEL[String, Int]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flatten the result with a fold.

```
result.fold(e => e.fail, x => x.liftFailNel)
```

Comment: Worked after little tuning: result inside (...) doesn't match the return type, so I had to do this: result.fold(e => e.fail, x => x.liftFailNel)